# Last Key in JavaScript array appearing as Length?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Bit of a weird one. Am using the following code build an array from a json object to make it easier to reference later in the code. However it would appear that when the last item of each array is created, rather than adding a new item, the Key of the item appears as the length of the array.

```
perfsJson = $.parseJSON(result);
var extras = new Array();
for (var i = perfsJson.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var obj = perfsJson[i];
    if (obj != null) {
        if (obj.Extras != null) {
            for (var perf_no in obj.Extras) {
                if (extras[perf_no] == undefined) {
                    var arr = new Array();
                    for (var extra in obj.Extras[perf_no]) {
                        if (arr[extra] == undefined) {
                            arr[extra] = obj.Extras[perf_no][extra];
                        }
                    }
                    extras[perf_no] = arr;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The resulting array appears as below:

[image: resulting array]

Any ideas what's going on here?

Edit:
Sample of Json below

{"Extras":{"32516":{"24186":"Example text"},"32515":{"24186":"Example text"},"32514":{"24186":"Example text"},"32512":{"24186":"Example text"},"32513":{"24186":"Example text"},"32511":{"24186":"Example text"},"32510":{"24186":"Example text"},"32509":{"24186":"Example text"},"32507":{"24186":"Example text"},"32503":{"24186":"Example text"},"32506":{"24186":"Example text"},"32505":{"24186":"Example text"},"32508":{"24186":"Example text"},"32502":{},"32497":{}}}

Comment: You should generally try to avoid missing keys in Javascript arrays. If you need to use a particular key, you need an object or a `Map` instead.

Comment: Looks like you're using `for...in` loops with arrays, and you get the `length` as well.

Comment: The code seems like JS version of https://twitter.com/dr4goonis/status/476617165463105536

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's going on hear is that you are using `for..in` to iterate over an array, which is a no-no because it iterates properties that are not the array elements (such as the `.length` property). Instead, use `Array#forEach`:

```
perfsJson = $.parseJSON(result);
var extras = new Array();
for (var i = perfsJson.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  var obj = perfsJson[i];
  if (obj != null) {
    if (obj.Extras != null) {
      obj.Extras.forEach(function (item, idx) {
        if (typeof extras[idx] === 'undefined') {
          var arr = new Array();
          item.forEach(function (item2, idx2) {
              if (typeof arr[idx2] === 'undefined') {
                  arr[idx2] = item2;
              }
          });
          extras[idx] = arr;
        }
      });
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

The innermost loop is pretty pointless and can be replaced with `Array#slice`:

```
perfsJson = $.parseJSON(result);
var extras = new Array();
for (var i = perfsJson.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  var obj = perfsJson[i];
  if (obj != null) {
    if (obj.Extras != null) {
      obj.Extras.forEach(function (item, idx) {
        if (typeof extras[idx] === 'undefined') {
          extras[idx] = item.slice();
        }
      });
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

The next inner loop can be replaced with `Array#map` and two `if` statements can be combined:

```
perfsJson = $.parseJSON(result);
var extras = new Array();
for (var i = perfsJson.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  var obj = perfsJson[i];
  if (obj != null&& obj.Extras != null) {
    extras = obj.Extras.map(function (item) {
        return item.slice();
    });
    break;
  }
}
```

In fact, most of this code can be simplified:

```
function findLastElement(arr) {
    for (var i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i -= 1) {
        if (arr[i] != null && arr[i].Extras != null) { return arr[i]; }
    }
}

perfsJson = $.parseJSON(result);
var lastElement = findLastElement(perfsJson);
var extras = lastElement
    ? lastElement.Extras.map(function (item) { return item.slice(); })
    : [];
```

Comment: Wow thanks, that's a seriously in depth answer. However if I try to use .forEach or .map I get an error saying "lastElement.Extras.map is not a function" or "lastElement.Extras.forEach is not a function". Any ideas?

Comment: @HuwD Is `lastElement.Extras` actually an array? Could you show us what your JSON looks like (not all of it, but a representative sample)? And what execution environment (browser, etc.) are you using?

Comment: I believe it's currently being handled as an object, have added sample of JSON to edit

Comment: @HuwD Thank you for adding that. Yes it is an object and it contains objects. Is there a reason you're trying to convert them into sparse arrays? Sparse arrays (arrays that have arbitrary indices instead of 0, 1, 2, 3, ...) are pretty unpopular and kind of hard to work with. It might be better if you just left them as objects.

Comment: Just to make it easier to reference from a later piece of code that uses another collection. The keys used for the top level array match up with values used in the later collection so I can match them up.

Comment: Looking at it you may be right about it being easier just to keep it as an object. Thanks for your help